# Posting data in form html to server using AngularJS Http Post

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to ask about posting problem, actually I have a form below, in that form, I have using ng-submit and ng-click for the function but it didn't work, can anyone help me?

```
<form method="post" class="sky-form" name="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="public/images/icon_namapasien.png" alt=""/> Nama Pasien</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10">
            <div ng-repeat="profile in profil">
                <label class="input disabled">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="profile.name">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-2">
            <a class="btnstatus">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="public/images/icon_tgl.png" alt=""/> Tanggal Lahir</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-3">
            <label class="select">
                <div ng-repeat="profile in profil">
                    <select name="gender" ng-model="profile.birth_date">
                        <option ng-repeat="n in range(01,31)" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-4">
            <label class="select">
                <div ng-repeat="profile in profil">
                    <select name="gender" ng-model="profile.birth_month">
                        <option value="01">Januari</option>
                        <option value="02">Februari</option>
                        <option value="03">Maret</option>
                        <option value="04">April</option>
                        <option value="05">Mei</option>
                        <option value="06">Juni</option>
                        <option value="07">Juli</option>
                        <option value="08">Agustus</option>
                        <option value="09">September</option>
                        <option value="10">Oktober</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">Desember</option>
                    </select>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
            <label class="select">
                <div ng-repeat="profile in profil">
                    <select name="gender" ng-model="profile.birth_year">
                        <option ng-repeat="n in range(1910,2016)" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-2">
            <a class="btnstatus">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="public/images/icon_gender.png" alt=""/> Jenis Kelamin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10">
            <div class="select">
                <label class="select">
                  <div ng-repeat="profile in profil">
                        <select name="gender" ng-model="profile.gender">
                                <option value="1">Pria</option>
                                <option value="0">Wanita</option>
                        </select>
                            <i></i>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-2">
            <a class="btnstatus">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="public/images/icon_alamat.png" alt=""/> Alamat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10">
            <div ng-repeat="profile in profil">
                <label class="input disabled">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="profile.address"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="0" ng-model="kodekota">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-2">
            <a class="btnstatus">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="public/images/icon_telp.png" alt=""/> Nomor Telepon / Hp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10">
            <div ng-repeat="profile in profil">
                <label class="input disabled">
                    <input type="text" value="" ng-model="profile.phone"/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-2">
            <a class="btnstatus">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <button class="btn-yellow" type="submit" name="submit" ng-click="postProfil()">Simpan Perubahan</button>
</form>
```

Here is the angularjs code

```
$scope.getProfil = function(){
    $http.get('/getUrl').success(function(data){
      $scope.profil = data;
    })
  }

  $scope.getProfil();

  $scope.profile = {};

  $scope.postProfil = function(){
    $http.post('/postUrl').success(function(data){
        $scope.getProfil();
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
  }

  $scope.range = function(min, max, step){
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
```

one thing for sure, I know that http.post using only link is a bad idea, but before I do that, I have debug it using alert javascript function, for example I want to get the data from profile.name so I alert it (profile.name) inside the postProfil function but it returns undefined.

here is the key that should be inputed in the http.post

1. address
2. phone
3. birth
4. gender
5. name

I would like to use the http array structure such as

```
$http.post({
method: 'POST',
url: '/postUrl',
data: {
//data is here
}
})
```

what do you guys think? Thanks

EDIT:

Maybe I will change my questions, do you know the code for updating data from previous data in an apiUrl using AngularJS? So my problem is that getProfil and postProfil is in the same key and value (but I think some of the keys are different).

Comment: Make a Rest API to do this. use ng-resource to do this

Comment: Would you mind to give me the example? @AhmadSharif

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ng-model $scope.profile`:

```
  $scope.postProfil = function(){
    $http.post('/postUrl', $scope.profile).success(function(data){
        $scope.getProfil();
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: I have used this and when getProfil() binding comes, there are no values inside it...

Comment: By the way thank you for the answer... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Check server side what happens

Comment: I am in front end only, but when I use postman, the values can be saved inside the server, is the problem on me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post('api/create/something', yourData)
```

should do the trick for your problem.

$http.post accepts (url, data?, options?)
$http on the other hand accepts (options) directly. You can use it like

```
$http({
    url: 'api/create/something',
    data: yourData,
    method: 'POST'
}).then(....)
```

This code works the same with the code above.

Regarding the inaccurate data binding. It might be case sensitivity issues, or serialization issues coming from your rest api configuration. Sometimes PascalCased variable does not bind to camelCased variables as it is. Some configurations are needed to be done.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, somehow I think that maybe in the backend there was a problem but I think not... Like I said in my question that I have alert the data but it returns "Undefined" I don't know where is my problem, even though it is about case sensitive, it will be recognized by me, until now the latest code in my PC is at above.

Comment: I think it's because profile.name is inside a ng-repeat directive. (ng-repeat="profile in profil"). In this case the variable "profile" won't be accessible through the controller as it is the iterator value when you iterate over the "profil" array.

Comment: If i use value instead of ng-model, the result will be null because 'value' and ng-model is clashing (I don't know the exact term for this) and the result is the field is not shown. So do you have any idea?

Comment: Using ng-value in an input gives you the ability to pre-set the data of that input, which also binds to the ng-model attached to it. However typing and changing the value of input does not reflect to ng-value, it only reflects to the ng-model assigned. So for capturing data from inputs, you must always use ng-model for it's final value. But like I said, the problem is that your form is inside an iterator (ng-repeat) and can only be accessible by iterating over the array called "profil" in your code.